# Problem with changePage (local file) in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova

I use phonegap and JQueryMobile to make a webapp,but when use
`$.mobile.changePage` it doesn't work and show `Error Loading Page`, then I have
a test, when I use `http://localhost/aa.html` use `changePage` is ok, but when I 
use in local file `file:///D:/aa.html`, then common link and the
`changePage` all not work, how to fix it?

I use the last version of JQuery and JQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
$.mobile.changePage("page.html")
```

use:

```
$.mobile.navigate("page.html")
```